# Pre Update middleware is not called when updating from a bulk operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to delete an object field from the documents whenever this field is empty and contains no sub fields.

For example if my schema is defined this way:

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const mySchema = new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  //...
  objAttr: {
    type: ObjSchema,
    default: () => undefined
  },
  //...
});

const myModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', mySchema);
```

I call the `pre` hook to unset the object field at each update:

```js
mySchema.pre("updateOne", function(next){
  if (this.objAttr && !this.objAttr.subField1 && !this.objAttr.subField2) {
    this.objAttr = undefined;
  }

  next();
});
```

But nothing happens and the pre update is not called.

The document is updated within a bulk operation that goes like this:

```js
const bulkOps = [];
//...
bulkOps.push({ updateOne: {
  'filter': { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(someIdValue) },
  'update': { $unset: { 'objAttr.subField1': 1, 'objAttr.subField2': 1 }},
}});

myModel.bulkWrite(bulkOps);
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a pre("update") middleware? In docs I see updateOne and findOneAndUpdate https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

Comment: @SuleymanSah I tried `updateOne` but there is always no change. My update is triggered inside a bulk operation, so I am not sure if this is why the pre("update) is not called. It looks like a different topic than that posted for the question, so I am going to update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bulk Write operations do not trigger middlewares. You may need to do individual update operations. [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite)

Comment: It seems like the middleware is not called at all, I updated my question with more information about my code, thanks!

Comment: @Strider Ah, Mongoose does not run middleware on bulkWrite operations. You probably just have to make individual updates for each one.

Comment: @Strider Sorry, just realized you said that in the title, woops!

Comment: Oh I see! can you please add a quote or a link to the documentation so I can accept your answer? Like you said, individual update is the only possible workaround since automatic update is not possible

Comment: @Strider Updated with relevant documentation link. In the description it says: "This function does not trigger any middleware, not save() nor update()."